# Using CopyIntoStorage from snowflake.sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to run a Snowflake query and dump the results in a parquet file in Snowflake stage. So far, I am running the query as a raw sql string:

```
query = f"COPY INTO @SNF_STAGE_NAME/DIR/{userid} FROM (SELECT * FROM <TABLE-NAME> WHERE <COLUMN-NAME> IN {tuple_var} FILE_FORMAT=(TYPE=PARQUET) OVERWRITE=TRUE HEADER=TRUE"

with self.db.session as session:
    result = session.execute(query)
```

The `userid` and `tuple_var` are coming as user input. After testing successfully, I now want to modify this query to include placeholders for SNF_STAGE_NAME, table name, column name, userid and tuple_var to avoid SQL injection threat. The SNF_STAGE_NAME, table name and column name are going to be hard coded string values and `userid` and `tuple_var` are parameters to the function executing the SQL.

I tried various string formatting options in python like using `%s`, f-string formatters, and `sqlalchemy` options like `text()` construct and passed the respective values in `.execute()` as a `dict` but it's not working. Moreover, all the examples that I see on the internet are either using `conn.execute()` or `engine.execute()`. I believe `.execute()` should work the same but maybe it is not working as expected with a `session` object?

While trying to make it work, I stumbled upon a `snowflake.sqlalchemy` class `CopyIntoStorage` but there is absolutely no documentation on this. I tried running the following:

```
copy_into = CopyIntoStorage(from_=<select query from above>, into=f"@SNF_STAGE_NAME/DIR/{userid}", formatter=PARQUETFormatter())
with self.db.session as session:
    result = session.execute(copy_into)
```

but it fails with `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_compiler_dispatch'.`

With no documentation available, I am also not able to figure out how to provide these additional options: `OVERWRITE=TRUE HEADER=TRUE"` from original query. Could someone please help me with using `CopyIntoStorage()` with proper placeholders in the values for `from_` and `into` parameters?

Comment: If you want to refer to objects, such as tables, you need to use the IDENTIFIER keyword as documented here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifier-literal

Comment: Since it is open source you can look at the examples directly from the tests done, see [here](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-sqlalchemy/blob/main/tests/test_copy.py)

Comment: Thank you @NickW! That really helped in what I wanted to do. I was looking at SQLAlchemy docs and they got me so confused. Finally, this link helped me made my way thru this silly syntactical problem.

Comment: Thanks @Sergiu, I had looked those tests before posting the question. But a second look helped me see it’s not possible for my use case since I needed to copy to `InternalStorage`.